# How to make a resumable upload in Google Drive?

Tags: upload, google-drive, api

I want to upload a large file to Google Drive, and since my connection is slow, I want to make a resumable upload so that I can shutdown the computer whenever I want.
I found this solution :
[Resumable upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads#resumable), but I can't understand how to use it. Any ideas?